# JQuery Alert will not stop displaying

Tags: jquery

i have this jquery code

```
$("#type, #date_from, #date_to").change(function(){
    checkFullDay();

    if($("#date_to").val() == "") {
        $("#date_to").val( $("#date_from").val() );
    }

    if($("#date_to").val() < $("#date_from").val()) {
        alert("Dates are invalid");
    }
});
```

and when the alert displays, it will not stop.

i have tried changing it to `return alert("Dates are invalid");`

and i also tried adding `return true` and `return false` after the alert but doing any of these stop it displaying completely.

how can i make it only display once?

```
function checkFullDay() {
    if($("#type").val() != "Full") {
        $("#date_to").attr("readonly", true);
        $("#date_to").val( $("#date_from").val() );
    } else {
        $("#date_to").attr("readonly", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your html?

Comment: Is you `checkFullDay` function changing any of these values?

Comment: updated question with that function

Comment: *"when the alert displays, it will not stop"*, exactly what do you mean by that. Is the alert constantly looping after you close it and preventing you from doing anything else. Or is it alerting on the change event when you are not expecting it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will continuously execute because you have not written condition for checking it just once. Adding a simple flag can solve your problem. Change the value of flag just for the first time and then add it in the condition In your code may be something like this

```
<script>
var flag=0;
$("#type, #date_from, #date_to").change(function(){
    checkFullDay();

       if($("#date_to").val() == "") {
           $("#date_to").val( $("#date_from").val() );
       }

       if($("#date_to").val() < $("#date_from").val() && flag!=1) {
         flag=1;
         alert("Dates are invalid");
       }
});
</script>
```

Comment: yep, that works. but then what about if the #date_to input is changed again to another date that is previous to #date_to ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to add your code in  $(document).ready(function(e){}). Below works for me. I hope this is what you are trying to achieve.

```
</head>
<body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){


$("#type, #date_from, #date_to").change(function(){


    if($("#date_to").val() == "") {
        $("#date_to").val( $("#date_from").val() );
    }

    if($("#date_to").val() < $("#date_from").val()) {
        alert("Dates are invalid");
    }
});
});
</script>
<div>
From:<input type="date" id="date_from" />

To:<input type="date" id="date_to" />

</div>
</body>

<html>
```